# Creating an offset bell curve

Tags: normal-distribution

This is half programming and half math, but I need the math portion answered as I'm no good at it.

I have a list of 10 objects and am randomly selecting and object from that list. I need the "average" of that list to be chosen most often, but the "average" is the 6th item of the list. I need my probabilities to stay the same, but to be offset by +1. I can't just add 1 however, as that will cause an error if it attempts to choose the last object in the list +1 since it won't exist.

My current method is simply picking a random number from 0 (first index of array) through 9 three times, then dividing the result by 3. The probabilities are exactly as I'd like it, but obviously I'm getting the 5th object the most often instead of the 6th.

Thanks in advance for the answers, and if this is insanely simple I apologize for my horrendous math skills.

Comment: So, all you need is to create a distribution on the numbers from 0 to 9 where the average value is 6?

Comment: You could use a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=9,p=6/9$. Or... you could just do exactly what you're doing now, add $1$, and mod by $10$ in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a distribution over those numbers that has an expected value of $6$:

- Probability of a number less than 9: $\frac2{30}$
- Probability of 9: $0.4$

I will leave it to you to verify that the average will in fact be 6.  To implement this distribution, do the following:

```
n = (uniform random number from 0 to 1)
if n < 0.4
    return 9
else
    return uniform random number from 1,2,...,8
```

If you'd like a distribution in which 6 is the average and the most common, you can have a binomial distribution with $n=9$ and $p=\frac69=\frac2/3$.  To program this distribution, you could do the following:

```
k = 0
for i = 1 to 9
    n = (uniform random number from 0 to 1)
    if n < 0.66
        k = k+1
return k
```

Comment: This method definitely is on the right track.
`sum([1 if random.random() < (6.0/9.0) else 0 for i in xrange(len(array)-1)])`
That's my line to implement what you've suggested (in python 2.7). I use random.random() instead of uniform as it returns the 0 to 1 without additional args. My problem however is that with this method I'm getting the #6 instead of the 6th index, which is actually 5. I suppose I should have been more specific with my question. I'm also noting that this method returns 5-8, often 9, but never less than 4. Any other suggestions to improve this method?

Comment: I just moved the -1 to the end of the line. Instead of looping over 9 items I now loop over all 10, but then modify it by one to get the 5th index. My mistake on that one. However, is still seems to favor the higher numbers than the lower. I'm unsure how to fix that.

Comment: I realized my mistake. 5/9 is what we're looking for since the first index is 0. It now works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work, sorry I wasn't able to respond earlier.